# Desktop application and storing SSL certificate files

Tags: .net, security, ssl, architecture, client-server

How safe and correct is it to store a client SSL certificate just as a file in the directory along with the application (desktop client-server application)? As I understand it, this is not critical for TLS, but perhaps more critical for mTLS?

Comment: A certificate is public data. However if you need to use a certificate to authenticate yourself you need the relevant private key, which, by its name alone, should be considered private and sensitive. Where/How to store it has multiple answers, your question is too vague. If you are in some cloud settings, there are "vaults" or "secrets manager" tailored to do those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL certificates are meant to be publicly distributed as they contain "public" key details needed by the other party for the desired purpose (signature verification, encryption, etc).
So, it is okay to store SSL certificates however you wish from cryptographic key material leakage point of view.

But, SSL certificates contains some additional like your company information in subject or SAN. If such details are sensitive to you, it makes sense to store it in a secure manner.

**Additional Information:**

If the question was about the SSL private key then it is fairly safe to store private keys encrypted with a strong passphrase.

But, a private key without a passphrase is a big NO.

Comment: "But, SSL certificates contains some additional like your company information in subject or SAN. If such details are sensitive to you, it makes sense to store it in a secure manner." If issued by a public CA, the certificate is in the certificate transparency logs anyway, which are public.

Comment: "If the question was about the SSL private key then it is fairly safe to store private keys encrypted with a strong passphrase." And then where do you store the passphrase so that the application can get the private key?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, and this is a good question. And what do you do with the password?

Comment: Yes, with transparency logs anyway who "really want" to look up the certificate details can find it, no doubt.
But, answering the question, it can be stored in a slightly secure manner, so that the certificate is not readily available unless someone "really want" to look for it.

Comment: Passphrase can be put into the application code in some encoded manner, so that the private key can only be opened by the application when needed.